# Conflicts and Errors with tools:replace in bazel android environment

Tags: java, android, bazel

I guess I don't understand Android manifests enough: I've been trying to figure this out for a while now and nothing seems to work:

I have a `bazel` environment set up and I have a `maven_install` to grab a bunch of android stuff and then a custom build rule that just generates a simple local repo with a `BUILD` file with some targets.  The purpose of this is to try and group things sensibly so I can load what I need as `@android//:whatever` targets.

The app in question is just a little demo app for some LaTeX related widgets I made.  The `android_library` target builds just fine, but when I try to build the `android_binary` target I get:

```
ERROR: C:/projects/java/latex/java/com/bdl/latex/android/demo/BUILD:1:15: Merging manifest for //java/com/bdl/latex/android/demo:app failed: (Exit 1): ResourceProcessorBusyBox.exe failed: error executing command (from target //java/com/b
dl/latex/android/demo:app) bazel-out\x64_windows-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6\bin\external\bazel_tools\src\tools\android\java\com\google\devtools\build\android\ResourceProcessorBusyBox.exe ... (remaining 1 argument skipped)
Error: D:\_bazel_out\fk7lkimo\execroot\bdl_latex\java\com\bdl\latex\android\demo\AndroidManifest.xml:20:19-74 Error:
        Attribute provider#androidx.startup.InitializationProvider@authorities value=(androidx.lifecycle.process.androidx-startup) from [@maven_android//:androidx_lifecycle_lifecycle_process] AndroidManifest16331845056188086597.xml:20:19
-74
        is also present at [@maven_android//:androidx_startup_startup_runtime] AndroidManifest9826536139099638492.xml:20:19-74 value=(androidx.startup.androidx-startup).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:authorities"' to <provider> element at AndroidManifest.xml:20:9-22:20 to override.
Jun 30, 2023 3:19:14 PM com.google.devtools.build.android.ResourceProcessorBusyBox processRequest
SEVERE: Error during processing
com.google.devtools.build.android.AndroidManifestProcessor$ManifestProcessingException: Manifest merger failed : Attribute provider#androidx.startup.InitializationProvider@authorities value=(androidx.lifecycle.process.androidx-startup) f
rom [@maven_android//:androidx_lifecycle_lifecycle_process] AndroidManifest16331845056188086597.xml:20:19-74
        is also present at [@maven_android//:androidx_startup_startup_runtime] AndroidManifest9826536139099638492.xml:20:19-74 value=(androidx.startup.androidx-startup).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:authorities"' to <provider> element at AndroidManifest.xml:20:9-22:20 to override.
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.AndroidManifestProcessor.mergeManifest(AndroidManifestProcessor.java:186)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.ManifestMergerAction.main(ManifestMergerAction.java:228)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.ResourceProcessorBusyBox$Tool$5.call(ResourceProcessorBusyBox.java:97)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.ResourceProcessorBusyBox.processRequest(ResourceProcessorBusyBox.java:251)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.ResourceProcessorBusyBox.main(ResourceProcessorBusyBox.java:181)

Exception in thread "main" com.google.devtools.build.android.AndroidManifestProcessor$ManifestProcessingException: Manifest merger failed : Attribute provider#androidx.startup.InitializationProvider@authorities value=(androidx.lifecycle.
process.androidx-startup) from [@maven_android//:androidx_lifecycle_lifecycle_process] AndroidManifest16331845056188086597.xml:20:19-74
        is also present at [@maven_android//:androidx_startup_startup_runtime] AndroidManifest9826536139099638492.xml:20:19-74 value=(androidx.startup.androidx-startup).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:authorities"' to <provider> element at AndroidManifest.xml:20:9-22:20 to override.
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.AndroidManifestProcessor.mergeManifest(AndroidManifestProcessor.java:186)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.ManifestMergerAction.main(ManifestMergerAction.java:228)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.ResourceProcessorBusyBox$Tool$5.call(ResourceProcessorBusyBox.java:97)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.ResourceProcessorBusyBox.processRequest(ResourceProcessorBusyBox.java:251)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.ResourceProcessorBusyBox.main(ResourceProcessorBusyBox.java:181)
Warning:
See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.
Target //java/com/bdl/latex/android/demo:app failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 191.291s, Critical Path: 98.62s
INFO: 1030 processes: 48 internal, 812 local, 170 worker.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Ok, so in two different things from my maven pull: `androidx_lifecycle_lifecycle_process` (directly present) and `androidx_startup_startup_runtime` (indirect) there is a specification for a `provider` for this value.

The recommendation is to add `tools:replace="android:authorities"` to `<provider>` element in `"AndroidManifest.xml"`.  But it doesn't specify which one.  None of the `AndroidManifest.xml` files I have in my project currently have a `<provider>` tag.

My "root" manifest (where the `android_binary` target is) looks like:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.bdl.latex.android.demo"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">

  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="28"
    android:targetSdkVersion="28"/>

</manifest>
```

and my main manifest file (where the `android_library` target is) looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.bdl.latex.android.demo.app">

  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="28"
    android:targetSdkVersion="28"/>

  <application
    android:name=".AndroidLatexDemoApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
      android:name=".LaTeXActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Things I've tried:

- Adding `tools:replace="android:authorities"` to the `<application>` tag, as I've seen for some other values.  This fails with:

```
ERROR: C:/projects/java/latex/java/com/bdl/latex/android/demo/app/BUILD:21:16: Merging manifest for //java/com/bdl/latex/android/demo/app:demo failed: (Exit 1): ResourceProcessorBusyBox.exe failed: error executing command (from target //
java/com/bdl/latex/android/demo/app:demo) bazel-out\x64_windows-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6\bin\external\bazel_tools\src\tools\android\java\com\google\devtools\build\android\ResourceProcessorBusyBox.exe ... (remaining 1 argument skipped)
Error: D:\_bazel_out\fk7lkimo\execroot\bdl_latex\java\com\bdl\latex\android\demo\app\AndroidManifest.xml:11:3-30:17 Error:                   
        tools:replace specified at line:11 for attribute android:authorities, but no new value specified                                     
Error: D:\_bazel_out\fk7lkimo\execroot\bdl_latex\java\com\bdl\latex\android\demo\app\AndroidManifest.xml Error:                              
        Validation failed, exiting                                                                                                           
Jun 30, 2023 3:32:06 PM com.google.devtools.build.android.ResourceProcessorBusyBox processRequest                                            
SEVERE: Error during processing                                                                                                              
com.google.devtools.build.android.AndroidManifestProcessor$ManifestProcessingException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.AndroidManifestProcessor.mergeManifest(AndroidManifestProcessor.java:186)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.ManifestMergerAction.main(ManifestMergerAction.java:228)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.ResourceProcessorBusyBox$Tool$5.call(ResourceProcessorBusyBox.java:97)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.ResourceProcessorBusyBox.processRequest(ResourceProcessorBusyBox.java:251)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.ResourceProcessorBusyBox.main(ResourceProcessorBusyBox.java:181)

Exception in thread "main" com.google.devtools.build.android.AndroidManifestProcessor$ManifestProcessingException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.AndroidManifestProcessor.mergeManifest(AndroidManifestProcessor.java:186)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.ManifestMergerAction.main(ManifestMergerAction.java:228)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.ResourceProcessorBusyBox$Tool$5.call(ResourceProcessorBusyBox.java:97)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.ResourceProcessorBusyBox.processRequest(ResourceProcessorBusyBox.java:251)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.ResourceProcessorBusyBox.main(ResourceProcessorBusyBox.java:181)
Warning:
See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.
Target //java/com/bdl/latex/android/demo:app failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.325s, Critical Path: 0.75s
INFO: 3 processes: 3 internal.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

- Adding a `<provider>` tag to the application.  Extracting values from the original error, I tried: `<provider android:authorities="androidx.startup.androidx-startup" android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider" />`  This brought back the original error.
- Keeping the `<provider>` tag and re-adding the `tools:replace` so the manifest looked like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  package="com.bdl.latex.android.demo.app">
...
  <application
     ...
    tools:replace="android:authorities">
    <provider android:authorities="androidx.startup.androidx-startup" android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider" />
    <activity>...</activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

This brought back the 2nd error, with `tools:replace specified at line:11 for attribute android:authorities, but no new value specified`

- Keeping the `<provider>` tag and moving the `tools:replace` attribute inside it (because the original error did specify that I should put it in a `<provider>` tag. This brought back the first error message again

Ok... well, when it gives this error message it does point to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in the root (`android_binary`) package, so... let's try some things there, even though that manifest is pretty empty.

- Add the `<provider>` tag with `tools:replace` included to that manifest file: Error 1 (conflict)
- Add `tools:replace="android:authorities"` to the root tag without a `<provider>`: error 2 (no new value)
- Add `tools:replace="android:authorities"` to the root tag and a separate `<provider>`: error 2 (no new value)

And at that point I gave up and wrote this.

Hopefully someone can help me find the correct incantation.